# Hi, I am using Taiga ui inputFiles component for the first time, how to I get the file content and set it to FormData API?(I am a newbie)

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, spring

In my use case, I have multiple document types and have to generate formControls for each document type dynamically. Similarly, for each document type there will be an inputFile component. To send file content to the backend using `FormData`, how do I access the file content from Polymorpheus content `TuiFileLike`.
[Taiga Documentation for InputFiles](https://taiga-ui.dev/components/input-files)

```
makeRequest(file: TuiFileLike): Observable<TuiFileLike | null> {
    this.loadingFiles$.next(file);
 
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    //something like this
}
```

the file here is of type TuiFileLike hence I cannot access the file content.